# Terminate an application in IOS & Background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm kinda confused with the following actions:

1) Pressing the home button - The application is now in 'background mode' - what does it really mean? (In more technical terms)

2) Double click the home button and drag the application out - What does IOS do in that case? Does it completely terminate the program? or it only wipes it out from the RAM while not giving it CPU time at all? (Just a suggestion).
And if that is the case, how do I get my application some CPU time even when it is 'dragged' out ? How does one terminates an application completely in iPhone?

Thanks !

Comment: [uiapplication delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In the background mode the application is till either kept in memory or it's memory is stored on disk (subject to the amount of memory used). It can be reactivated if it uses certain background modes, e.g. playing audio, monitoring location or receiving the relevant push notification telling it to wake up.

2) The application is totally killed. This is the way that one terminates an application and the app cannot get any CPU time in this state.

Comment: Thanks. How come that even when I drag out WhatsApp I still keep getting on messages? It seems that the application just restarts it self.

Comment: No, the push notifications are separate. They are handled by Apple. The application will not wake up unless the user selects the notification. The application won't be "aware" that the push notification was received at this point.

Comment: Are the push notifications a separate process which comes along with the application ? (Say WhatsApp)

Comment: They are handled in a central service that is part of the OS. Applications just register for notifications, the server then sends the notification to the device through Apple's servers. Developers do not need to (nor can they) write any code to handle the display of push notifications outside of their app.